# Jetpack Compose detectTransformGestures consumes all gestures

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose

I have taken a look at the following answer and it didn't work [How to use detectTransformGestures but not consuming all pointer event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71156016/how-to-use-detecttransformgestures-but-not-consuming-all-pointer-event)

The ***problem***: I have a LazyList that I need to scroll vertically, the children composables also are draggable horizontally and respond to tap and presses. But, I want the LazyList to also be pinched-in or pinched-out while still intercepting the drag gestures. Here's the current code of the modifier for the existing gestures:

```kotlin
           /* LazyList child composable */ 
           Modifier.pointerInput(myLock) {
               detectDragGestures(
                   onDragEnd = {
                       if (fooBolean) {
                           stuffToDo()
                        },
                   onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                        draggingTheComposableLogic()

                        scope.launch {
                            /* Scrolling the lazylist using the state linked to it */ 
                            state.scroll {
                                 scrollBy(-dragAmount.y)
                            }
                        }
                   }
                )
           }
           .pointerInput(Unit) {
               detectTapGesturesUnconsumed(
                   onTap = {
                       scope.launch {
                            val press = PressInteraction.Press(Offset.Zero)
                            clickInteraction.emit(press)
                            delay(150)           
                            clickInteraction.emit(PressInteraction.Release(press))
                       }

                   }
                )
            }
```

My **attempt**: I tried modifying the source code for detectTransformGestures to remove the consume part, but it doesn't work at all. It worked for tap and drag, but not for transform gestures. If I add this piece of code to detect zoom-in and zoom-out (pinch gesture), then everything else will just stop working:

```kotlin
/* This surface is situated on top of the lazylist, i know it's overlaying it, but then if I add the pointerInput modifier to the lazylist, it also won't work, nothing works, it seems like this modifier keeps blocking until the pointers are lifted */
Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().alpha(0f)
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectTransformGestures(
                            onGesture = { c, p, z, r ->

                                Log.e("f", "$z")
                            }
                        )
                    }
                ) {}
```

Is there any way I can detect ONLY-ZOOM gesture without consuming it, so I can intercept the other gestures normally ?